# KIVY_VIDEO provider not selecting ffpyplayer

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to run the share/kivy-examples/demo/kivy-catalog example on Ubuntu 18.04.
I keep getting

```
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: gstplayer
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image </home/erik/anaconda3/envs/kivyenv/share/kivy-examples/widgets/cityCC0.mpg>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading texture ../../widgets/cityCC0.mpg
...
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event6". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[WARNING] [VideoGstplayer] b"No decoder available for type 'video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)true, mpegversion=(int)1'."
[ERROR  ] [VideoGstplayer] b'Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.'
[ERROR  ] [VideoGstplayer] b'Internal data stream error.'
```

despite having Gstreamer (or atleast the good/bad/ugly, whatever that is). The [installation page](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html) notes that Gstreamer is not included, but I checked with `apt list --installed *gstreamer*` that I have those packages.
Then I tried to use ffpyplayer - I've set the environment variable in the terminal using `KIVY_VIDEO=ffpyplayer` and even in the python file  via
`os.environ['KIVY_VIDEO'] = 'ffpyplayer'`
But kivy keeps using gstplayer, as seen in the [INFO] line above.

How can I either get this to work with gstreamer/gstplayer or get kivy to use ffpyplayer? I installed the latter with pip.
I also installed the ubuntu-restricted-extras after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607522/no-decoder-available-for-type-video-x-h264) and [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fix-missing-plugin-gstreamer-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

All the simpler kivy examples have worked so far ("hello world").

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874166/kivy-unable-to-open-device-dev-input-event7-on-ubuntu-no-permission) says not to worry about the permissions warning on "/dev/input/event6", so I won't.

Answer (score 0):

I more closely examined my installation. I realized from the [install page](https://kivy.org/#download) that kivy requires python < 3.8. I removed my virtual environment, and created a new one using python 3.7. `conda install kivy -c conda-forge`  downloaded gstreamer and gst-plugins-base along with kivy. I can now run sll but the media section the kivycatalog/main.py
The media section of the catalog still shows warnings and errors in the terminal, the same as before.